# Format dictionaries from Coordinate Matrix with row/column to original id

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns `user_id`, `product_code`, `score` and i convert it to [coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html). Every row represents a `user_id` and every column a `product_code`. The values in the matrix are either the scores or Nan values because of the sparse formation. I have to use a sparse matrix because is memory efficient and my dataset is very large.

Which is the fastest way to map the `row/columns` with `user_id` and `product_code`?

I am currently using this function for the users and the same for the products but instead of `.row` I use `.col`

```
def user_row_dictionary(df, coo_matrix):

    row_to_user_id= dict()
    inter = np.array(df['user_id'])
    for i in range(len(coo_matrix.row)):
        row_to_user_id[coo_matrix.row[i]] = inter[i]

    user_id_to_row = { v: k for k, v in row_to_user_id.items() }

    return row_to_user_id, user_id_to_row
```

The function works great but I want a faster way to do that.

The documentation doesn't provide a standard function for that.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `row_to_contact_id`? Maybe it's `row_to_user_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are just pairing the elements of `row` with those of `inter` on a one to one basis.  You can construct such a dictionary with one statement:

```
In [45]: inter = np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
In [46]: row = np.array([0,1,2,3])
In [47]: dict(zip(row, inter))
Out[47]: {0: 'one', 1: 'two', 2: 'three', 3: 'four'}
In [48]: dict(zip(inter, row))
Out[48]: {'four': 3, 'one': 0, 'three': 2, 'two': 1}
```